# Android Converting .NET Path.Combine to java?

Tags: .net, android

We are converting apps to Android from .NET

Is there a Java equivalent of the .NET Path.Combine() function?

Currently we check the / on each folder etc before building paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import java.io.File;

// ...

public static String pathCombine(String path1, String path2)
{
    File parent = new File(path1);
    File child = new File(parent, path2);
    return child.getPath();
}
```